# How to set time interval in datetime-local input control

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, date, datetime-local

I am using the [`step`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/step) attribute to set a 15 minutes time interval:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" step="900" />
```

When I enter the time using the keyboard, it works fine, but it doesn't when I try to enter it through the UI control:

[image: datetime input control]

How can I configure the UI to apply the desired time interval?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.